# Большие Sql - запросы

Tags: php, sql

Сколько будет выполняться команда select * from table where id = 1, если в таблице будет около 20000 строк?
И как можно будет оптимизировать такой запрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Сколько будет выполняться команда select * from table where id = 1, если в таблице будет около 20000 строк?

Зависит от того, сколько записей будет отобрано, имеется ли индекс по `id` и насколько быстр канал от сервера до клиента. Ну и куча менее значимых факторов. Но в любом случае 20к записей - это "ниачём".

> как можно будет оптимизировать такой запрос

1. Создать индекс по `id`, если его нет;
2. Заменить звёздочку на реально необходимый список полей выходного набора.

Comment: select ass.idProduct, d.title,d.photo,d.shtrihCode, d.description
  FROM assortment ass
  INNER JOIN product d ON ass.idProduct = d.id
        where ass.idProduct = id group by ass.idProduct

Comment: Гм... какая связь этого кода с исходным вопросом? Ну и группировка в нём странная - в MySQL это выбор случайных значений из правой таблицы (и не факт что из одной записи), проще заменить её на LIMIT 1, а остальные СУБД вообще дадут ошибку.

Comment: В общем если я буду искать по айдишнику запись в таблицу 20000 тыс. записями, то скорость выполнения запроса сильно не измениться, если к примеру в таблице будет записей 1000. Я правильно понял?

Comment: @Vadim не изменится, в случае наличия индекса и примерно одинакового кол-ва записей с одним id. Почитайте про индексы, что бы понимать что это такое и как используется, тогда вопросов по скорости работы гораздо меньше станет

Comment: Спасибо за вашу помощь. Возможно вы подскажете какие книги можно почитать?

Comment: *если я буду искать по айдишнику запись в таблицу 20000 тыс. записями, то скорость выполнения запроса сильно не измениться, если к примеру в таблице будет записей 1000.* В первом приближении это 15 сравнений в первом случае и 10 во втором. Поскольку всё происходит в памяти (размер индекса таблицы будет скорее всего меньше блока чтения ОС), разницу померить не удастся.